# How to flatten a PolygonZ onto the XY-plane using pygis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, polygon, geometry-conversion, multi-polygon

I want to flatten/project a PolygonZ onto the XY-plane. Although I wished for a method to flatten the whole object with the option of letting me decide what direction of the the line needs to be reproduced (which maybe be another feature to be added/discussed) all I found was a method to drop the Z values. That would be a good start but yet that's where I'm stuck:

feature.geometry() output says it is a MultiPolygonZ and contains a PolygonZ:

> <QgsGeometry: MultiPolygonZ (((280.79399999999441206 831.82999958276749 520.36000000000001364 ...>

So I unpack/flatten it:
`line2=feature.geometry().asGeometryCollection()`

My debug output for line2 states:

> line 2 [<QgsGeometry: PolygonZ ((280.79399999999441206 831.82999958276749 520.36000000000001364, 273.037999999942258 830.07299999985843897 520.36000000000001364, 271.95100000000093132 834.73300000000745058 520.36000000000001364, 271.90700000000651926 834.92399999964982271 520.36000000000001364, 279.68900000001303852 836.57500000018626451 520.36000000000001364, 279.7099999999627471 836.57899999991059303 520.36000000000001364, 278.26000000000931323 842.85999984353781 520.36000000000001364, 276.78899999998975545 849.21999999973922968 520.36000000000001364, 273.65800000005401671 862.79999955296516 520.36000000000001364, 272.45499999995809048 867.97599999979138374 520.36000000000001364, 270.94799999997485429 874.50299999956041574 520.36000000000001364, 298.23999999999068677 880.75299999956041574 520.36000000000001364, 300.49999997392297 870.90099999960511923 520.36000000000001364, 300.95200000004842877 8...>]

Then I tried
line2_polygonXY=QgsLineString(line2[0])
but that didn't work.

The geometry class is only able to convert to objects like QgsPolygonXY, QgsPolylineXY, QPolygonF and so on, but no PolygonZ is offered. No idea what QPolygonF is, there's no documentation but it seems to be some Qt5 Polygon object representation.

How do I cast/convert this PolygonZ to a QgsLineString? In the documentation I found out that Z-values of a QgsLineString can be dropped easily afterwards but I couldn't find any hint in the docs how to convert from PolygonZ to QgsLineString. Any ideas how to achieve this?

My next step would then be:

> line2_polygonXY.dropZValue()

Answer (score 1):

@ndawson already provided the answer:

```
multi_polygon = feature.geometry()

for part in multi_polygon.parts():
# part should be a QgsPolygon object
print(part)

# get exterior ring of polygon:
exterior = part.exteriorRing().clone()
# exterior should be a QgsLineString, with LineStringZ type
print(exterior)

# drop the z
exterior.dropZValue()
# exterior will be LineString
print(exterior)

# alternatively set the z to something different
exterior.setZValue(3)
```

There's also

```
lines = feature.geometry().coerceToType(QgsWkbTypes.LineString)
```

which should give you a list of linestrings back representing ALL the
rings for ALL the polygon parts